# Configurar a planilha criada pelo java com jxl

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gera um planilha de excel com dados recolhidos de outros arquivos, para isso estou utilizando jxl, o aplicação já está gerando a planilha corretamente, porém preciso alterar algumas configurações dessas planilhas, como por exemplo, o tamanho da coluna, também preciso colocar toda a planilha de forma que as informações sejam exibidas centralizadas. Porém a única coisa que consegui modificar foi o estilo da fonte e a cor do fundo, não encontrei onde posso fazer essas outras modificações. Se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

#### Update

Código (com cabeçalhos centralizados porém colunas ainda não alinhadas):

```
if (arquivos != null) {
    for (int x = 0; x < arquivos.length; x++) {
        if (arquivos[x].getName().endsWith("pdf")) {
            File f = arquivos[x];
            try (RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream acesso = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath())) {
                PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(acesso);
                parser.parse();
                COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
                PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);

                WritableWorkbook planilha = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(outPath + f.getName().replace(".pdf", ".xls"))); // Cria um arquivo XLS
                WritableSheet aba = planilha.createSheet("Lote " + f.getName().replace(".pdf", ""), 0); // Nome da aba do arquivo XLS

                String cabecalho[] = new String[4];
                cabecalho[0] = "Página";
                cabecalho[1] = "Autorização";
                cabecalho[2] = "Status Leitura";
                cabecalho[3] = "Retorno Ticket Log";

                Colour bckcolor = Colour.DARK_BLUE; // Cor do fundo do cabeçalho
                WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat();
                cellFormat.setBackground(bckcolor);

                cellFormat.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);

                WritableFont fonte = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL); // Formato da fonte do cabeçalho
                fonte.setColour(Colour.WHITE); // Cor da fonte do cabeçalho
                cellFormat.setFont(fonte);

                WritableCellFormat cellFormat2 = new WritableCellFormat();
                cellFormat2.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);

                for (int z = 0; z < cabecalho.length; z++) {
                    Label label = new Label(z, 0, cabecalho[z]);
                    aba.addCell(label);
                    WritableCell cell = aba.getWritableCell(z, 0);
                    cell.setCellFormat(cellFormat);
                }

                List<String> linhasGravadas = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 1; i <= pdDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                    pdfStripper.setStartPage(i);
                    pdfStripper.setEndPage(i);
                    String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);

                    String aut = "";
                    String Status = "";
                    String pagina = Integer.toString(i);


                    Label label = new Label(0, i, pagina);
                    aba.addCell(label);

                    label = new Label(1, i, aut);
                    aba.addCell(label);

                    label = new Label(2, i, Status);
                    aba.addCell(label);
                }

                planilha.write();
                planilha.close();
                acesso.close();
            } catch (WriteException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(testeXML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            f.renameTo(new File(outPath , f.getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode centralizar o texto de uma célula utilizando o método [`setAlignment`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/jxl/write/WritableCellFormat.html#setAlignment(jxl.format.Alignment)) da classe `WritableCellFormat`. Por exemplo:

```
WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat();
cellFormat.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
```

Esse formato pode ser passado no construtor de um `Label`, e.g:

```
Label label = new Label(0, 1, "conteúdo", cellFormat);
```

Alternativamente você também pode setar esse formato separadamente com o método [`setCellFormat`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableCell.html#setCellFormat(jxl.format.CellFormat)), e.g.:

```
Label outroLabel = new Label(0, 1, "outro conteúdo");
outroLabel.setCellFormat(cellFormat);
```

Já o tamanho da coluna pode ser configurado com o método [`setColumnView`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableSheet.html#setColumnView(int%2C%20int)) da classe `WritableSheet`. Por exemplo:

```
WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Minha aba", 0);
// primeira coluna com espaço para 30 caracteres
sheet.setColumnView(0, 30);
// segunda coluna com espaço para 50 caracteres
sheet.setColumnView(1, 50);
```

---

#### Fontes:

- [BE THE CODER > How to Align Text Horizontally in Excel Cells](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/excel/jexcel-api/how-to-align-text-horizontally-in-excel-cells.html)
- [Code Project - How to set the width for each column when write excel file using JExcel API in java](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/553125/Howplustoplussetplusthepluswidthplusforpluseachplu)